# Multilanguage elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, multilingual

I will be indexing posts in ElasticSearch. For now there are two languages: English and Chinese. So Each post has one (English) or two translations plus some data that are common for both languages. My question is how should I index posts?

1. Create two indices: `posts-en` and `posts-cn` and store posts separately?
2. Create single index `posts` and keep data in format like this:

   ```
   {
     commonParam1: 1,
     commonParam2: "somevalue",
     ...
     titleEn: "English title",
     titleCn: "Chinese title",
     contentEn: "Content EN",
     contentCn: "Content CN",
     ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a compelling reason to split a single document across two indexes I'd strongly advise keeping it all in one index.

With one index you can easily use a different analyzer for each each language specific field. Adding additional mappings in the future for new languages is fairly straightforward. It allows you to index each document in a single call as opposed to two, one for each language, if you index separately. You reduce duplicated data (e.g. the common data).

I'd also take a good look at this post: http://gibrown.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/three-principles-for-multilingal-indexing-in-elasticsearch/

It's a good discussion on analyzing and indexing for multiple languages into Elasticsearch.